# Yarn Lockfile has incorrect entry for x

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

My project is a monorepo using Yarn Workspaces.

Why does my Yarn Lockfile give this warning?  How does it happen?  What can you do to fix it?

Yarn version 1.22.19

```
warning Lockfile has incorrect entry for "@typescript-eslint/parser@^2.34.0". Ignoring it.
warning Lockfile has incorrect entry for "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@2.x". Ignoring it.
warning Lockfile has incorrect entry for "@typescript-eslint/parser@2.x". Ignoring it.
warning Lockfile has incorrect entry for "@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin@^0.4.3". Ignoring it.
warning Lockfile has incorrect entry for "tslib@^1.10.0". Ignoring it.
warning Lockfile has incorrect entry for "graphql@^14.5.8". Ignoring it.
warning Lockfile has incorrect entry for "tslib@^1.9.3". Ignoring it.
warning Lockfile has incorrect entry for "graphql@^14.7.0". Ignoring it.
warning Lockfile has incorrect entry for "browserslist@4.10.0". Ignoring it.
warning Lockfile has incorrect entry for "graphql-tag@2.12.4". Ignoring it.
warning Lockfile has incorrect entry for "browserslist@4.7.0". Ignoring it.
warning Lockfile has incorrect entry for "browserslist@^2.11.3". Ignoring it.
warning Lockfile has incorrect entry for "browserslist@4.1.1". Ignoring it.
warning Lockfile has incorrect entry for "tslib@~2.4.0". Ignoring it.
warning Lockfile has incorrect entry for "browserslist@^4.20.3". Ignoring it.
warning Lockfile has incorrect entry for "tslib@1.11.1". Ignoring it.
warning Lockfile has incorrect entry for "tslib@^1.11.1". Ignoring it.
warning Lockfile has incorrect entry for "prettier@~2.2.1". Ignoring it.
warning Lockfile has incorrect entry for "emeth@^1.0.2". Ignoring it.
warning Lockfile has incorrect entry for "tslib@^1.9.0". Ignoring it.
warning Lockfile has incorrect entry for "typescript@~4.1.3". Ignoring it.
warning Lockfile has incorrect entry for "browserslist@4.14.2". Ignoring it.
warning Lockfile has incorrect entry for "prettier@^1.9.2". Ignoring it.
warning Lockfile has incorrect entry for "tslib@~2.1.0". Ignoring it.
warning Lockfile has incorrect entry for "browserslist@^4.20.2". Ignoring it.
warning Lockfile has incorrect entry for "browserslist@^4.21.2". Ignoring it.
warning Lockfile has incorrect entry for "tslib@^1.8.1". Ignoring it.
warning Lockfile has incorrect entry for "tslib@~2.2.0". Ignoring it.
warning Lockfile has incorrect entry for "tslib@^1". Ignoring it.
warning Lockfile has incorrect entry for "browserslist@^3.2.6". Ignoring it.
warning Lockfile has incorrect entry for "eslint@^4.0.0". Ignoring it.
warning Lockfile has incorrect entry for "prettier@^1.7.0". Ignoring it.
warning Lockfile has incorrect entry for "typescript@^2.5.1". Ignoring it.
warning Lockfile has incorrect entry for "node-gyp@^5.0.2". Ignoring it.
warning Lockfile has incorrect entry for "tslib@^1.0.0". Ignoring it.
```